# Lag between windowed/fullscreen switch

Tags: c#, xna, fullscreen

I am creating a XNA game and added the option to use the game in fullscreen or windowed.

```
         // full screen on
        if (optionsMenu.buttonWithIndexPressed(7) && !game.graphics.IsFullScreen)
        {
            game.settings.fullScreen = true;
            game.graphics.ToggleFullScreen();
        }
        //fullscreen off
        if (optionsMenu.buttonWithIndexPressed(8) && game.graphics.IsFullScreen)
        {
            game.settings.fullScreen = false;
            game.graphics.ToggleFullScreen();

        }
```

When I change this option, everything works fine except for the lag causing all the screen to go black for a few seconds. This lag is really bothering me. Is it possible one way or another, to reduce the time for the lag?

Comment: It's not [lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag). I am noob in `xna`, but I am pretty sure, what switching to/from fullscreen mode is **a huge lot to do** with the graphic system. What you can do is to not go into real fullscreen, but use some *fakes* (borderless window of desktop size), this is for sure less costly and will not bother you that much anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing a borderless window approach (even through such a thing is not truly supported in XNA) with the following (untested):

```
IntPtr hWnd = this.Window.Handle;
var control = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle( hWnd );
var form = control.FindForm();
form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

However, your game is going to stutter for a moment whenever you resize, as the backbuffers will need to be re-initialized.  There are hacky ways to avoid any hiccups on resizing, but not for going actually fullscreen, hence the borderless window reccommendation.

Also, keep your `LoadContent()` implementation as short as possible, and only load in what you need at the time.   `LoadContent()` will be called every time your D3D (XNA) window changes context and will halt your game until it finishes reloading all resources, so consider loading your resources more dynamically.

---

#### Additional Info

Consider making a texture to which your game renders all passes.  Then draw that final game texture (which is at your lower, desired resoloution) onto your actual backbuffer (which is your higher, screen resolution) with a very simple point sample shader.

```
//yourxnarenderclass.cs
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); //targets your backbuffer, which should be your full screen resolution
yourEffect.Parameters["InputTexture"].SetValue(finalGameTexture);
yourEffect.CurrentTechnique = yourEffect.Techniques["Simple"];
foreach (EffectPass pass in yourEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    quadRender.Render(Vector2.One * -1, Vector2.One);
}
```

To read more about rendering with quads, see [Using a Basic Effect with Texturing (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051.aspx)

Your input sampler is standard:

```
//HLSL effect.fx
texture InputTexture; 
sampler inputSampler = sampler_state      
{
            Texture   = <InputTexture>;
            MipFilter = Point;
            MinFilter = Point;
            MagFilter = Point;
            AddressU  = Clamp;
            AddressV  = Clamp;
};
```

And your pixel shader:

```
VS_OUTPUT FullScreenVS( float3 InPos  : POSITION,
                        float2 InTex  : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VS_OUTPUT Out = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    // Offset the position by half a pixel to correctly align texels to pixels
    Out.Position = float4(InPos,1) + 0.5f* float4(-1.0f/renderTargetSize.x, 1.0f/renderTargetSize.y, 0, 0);
    Out.TexCoords = InTex;
    return Out;
}
```

This is tried and tested.  There's more code involved, but it's too complex to go into detail here.  I suggest reading up on how to implement your own [Effects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.effect.aspx) in XNA so the code above will make more sense in context.

Comment: Waow, that's really a lot faster but I really need what `graphics.ToggleFullscreen` does. Meaning that I'd like to preserve the old resolution when the game goes to fullscreen.

Comment: What you could do is use this method but set your backbuffers to be fullscreen monitor resolution, then have a final output shader that just blits your game's finalized view, from say 640x480 or whatever your game is, to the backbuffer which is at monitor resolution.  **Be sure** that your sampling filter mode is Point for this!  Point sampling ensures nice clear edges between texels, which is great for preserving that retro look and sounds like what you are looking for.  You cannot do what you are asking with `graphics.ToggleFullscreen` as that *changes video modes*.

Comment: Could you update the answer with the code to preserve the same resolution?

Comment: I've added some information.  It's hard to cover the entire XNA rendering pipeline in an answer, so ive just included the Effect bits that you'll need.  Hopefully it at least sets you on the right path, It took me forever to figure out.